# What is the representation matrix of this operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

To determine the eigenvalues of $L$ I need a representation matrix of:

$$L: \mathbb{R} [X]_p \to \mathbb{R} [X]_p,\quad f \mapsto [(1-X^2)f']' $$

where $\mathbb{R} [X]_p$ is the vector space of polynomials with real coefficients with degree at most $p$. How I can find a matrix representation?

Comment: you want the representation of the operator $L$, what is not a polynomial. Choose a basis for $\Bbb R[X]_p$ and define a matrix from it.

Comment: Have you considered computing the eigenvalues directly?

Comment: In the spirit of @amd's suggestion: My, that differential equation [looks familiar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix of linear transformation depends on a choice of basis, so let 
$$\mathcal{A}=\left\{\alpha_1=1,\alpha_2=X,\alpha_3=X^2,...,\alpha_p+1=X^p\right\}$$ be a basis of $\mathbf{R}[X]_p$.

So,$$L(\alpha_n)=\left(\left(1-X^2\right)\left(X^{n-1}\right)'\right)'=\left(\left(1-X^2\right)\left(n-1\right)X^{n-2}\right)'=-n\left(n-1\right)X^{n-1}+\left(n-1\right)\left(n-2\right)X^{n-3}=\left(n-1\right)\left(n-2\right)\alpha_{n-2}-n\left(n-1\right)\alpha_n$$ 
for $n>2$, you can find the values of $L(\alpha_1),L(\alpha_2)$ easily.

Now, by definition of matrix of linear transformation $A=
\left[L(\alpha_1)_\mathcal{A}\,L(\alpha_2)_\mathcal{A}\cdots L(\alpha_p)_\mathcal{A}\right]$ where columns $L(\alpha_i)_\mathcal{A}$ are coordinates of $L(\alpha_i)$, for example if $L(\alpha_5)=12\alpha_3-20\alpha_5$ then $$L(\alpha_5)_\mathcal{A}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\12\\0\\-20\\0\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore matrix of $L$ in basis $\mathcal{A}$ is 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&2&0&0&0&\cdots\\
0&-2&0&6&0&0&\cdots\\
0&0&-6&0&12&0&\cdots\\
0&0&0&-12&0&20&\cdots\\
0&0&0&0&-20&0&\cdots\\
\end{pmatrix}=[a_{ij}],$$ where $a_{ij}=\left\{
\begin{align}
-i(i-1)&&1<i=j\leq p\\
(j-1)(j-2)&&0<j\leq p\,\textrm{and}\, j=i+2\\
0&&\textrm{otherwise}
\end{align}\right.$

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a basis for $\mathbb{R}[X]_p$, $f_1, \dots, f_n$.

Compute the coefficients of $L(f_1), \dots, L(f_n)$ in that basis.

Then the $A_{ij}$ entry of the matrix is the $f_i$ coefficient of $L(f_j)$.

See 15.10 of for a more general formulation of this:
https://www.math.ku.edu/~lerner/m290/Chapter15.pdf

See for some examples: http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/~sellerme/sfehtml/classes/math3260/m3260sp03sec19notes.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To define a matrix that represent $L$ choose a basis of $\mathbb{R} [X]_p$ that I will name $v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_p$. Now the coefficients of a matrix $A$ (noted as $A_{j,k}$) are defined by

$$Lv_k=\sum_{j=0}^p A_{j,k}v_j,\quad\forall j,k\in\{0,1,\ldots,p\}$$

If you can find a basis such that

$$Lv_k\in\operatorname{span}(v_0,\ldots,v_j),\quad\forall k\le j$$

then the representation matrix would be upper-triangular (then the eigenvalues of $L$ lie in the diagonal of this matrix). However the existence of upper-triangular matrices are not ensured for operators on real vector spaces.